# does the column we use in group by effect the sorting order of the table?

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

there are two tables

1. teacher(id,dept,name,phone,mobile)
2. dept(id,name)

here teacher.dept acts as a foreign key for dept table. now they are asking to show each department and the number of staff in the sorted manner.
so here are two queries which produce same result

1. select dept.name ,count(teacher.name) from teacher right join dept on(teacher.dept=dept.id) group by dept.id
2. select dept.name ,count(teacher.name) from teacher right join dept on(teacher.dept=dept.id) group by teacher.dept order by count(teacher.name) desc

the above two queries produce the correct result. but i don't understand why i have to use the order by clause explicitly in query no 2 and why with out even mentioning order by clause the first query produced in the sorted manner. what makes the difference between the two and why??

can you please help me with this?

Comment: no, the group by will not influence the order

Comment: It could well be a coincidence based on the data in the table and the way mysql aggregates it internally.  Provide actual table definitions and test data, ideally in a fiddle site such as dbfiddle.uk , and we can give you an actual reason

Comment: If you don't use `ORDER BY`, the ordering of the results is chosen arbitrarily by MySQL, and you shouldn't depend on any particular order. I've usually found that it orders by the column I'm grouping on, so I'm surprised your results were ordered by the count.

Comment: BTW, grouping by a column in the child table is usually wrong. All the departments with no teachers will be grouped together because `teacher.dept` will be `NULL`. Use `GROUP BY dept.id`.

Comment: @nbk this depends on the mysql version used

Comment: `dept.id` is, I'm guessing, the primary key of your department table. While you should never depend on it, generally results will be ordered by primary key and indices if no other order is specified. But I repeat, don't depend on this, because the query optimizer can surprise you on which index it uses.